# Assigning Columns for a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to work with an api for betting odds to download odds for college football head 2 head moneylines, spreads, and overs for each game. The api response is a list with lists inside of it. For example, when calling the first index of the list the response is:

```
{'away_team': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
 'bookmakers': [{'key': 'fanduel',
                 'last_update': '2022-08-16T15:32:02Z',
                 'markets': [{'key': 'h2h',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
                                            'price': -530},
                                           {'name': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
                                            'price': 390}]},
                             {'key': 'spreads',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
                                            'point': -12.5,
                                            'price': -110},
                                           {'name': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
                                            'point': 12.5,
                                            'price': -110}]},
                             {'key': 'totals',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Over',
                                            'point': 50.5,
                                            'price': -110},
                                           {'name': 'Under',
                                            'point': 50.5,
                                            'price': -110}]}],
                 'title': 'FanDuel'}],
 'commence_time': '2022-08-27T16:30:00Z',
 'home_team': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
 'id': 'a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb',
 'sport_key': 'americanfootball_ncaaf',
 'sport_title': 'NCAAF'}
```

For the game between Northwestern and Nebraska. I am able to create a dataframe with the home team, away team, and start time with the dataframe columns in the code below, but I am not sure how to navigate into the api list to also assign columns for the spread odds (their key is listed as 'price' in the api list object). Thank you for any input

```
odds_json = odds_response.json()
    print('Number of events:', len(odds_json))
    df = pd.DataFrame(odds_json, columns = ['home_team', 'away_team', 'commence_time', 'price'])
    print(df)
```

Comment: It looks like the data you are after live under a key called `bookmakers`. I'm not exactly sure how you want to store the data in the dataframe, but you'll need a write a function to parse the `bookmakers` key into what you want. For what it is worth, a dataframe may not be the best option since these data seem like they would require a multiindex. You might be better off making a custom class that parses the data and make it available how you wish.

Comment: It is telling me the data type is a list for some reason, even though it looks like a dict. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: If you set `data={your_dict}` and then do `data["bookmakers"]` you do get a list and that is probably because you could get the price and over under values from multiple different book keepers. In your example data, you only have data from one bookkeeper, `fanduel` but I suppose the API you are using could return multiple. This is why I don't think a DataFrame is a good choice. You should either work directly with these dictionaries, or create a custom class. For what its worth, if you try jsontopydantic.com it does a decent job defining good models for this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`' `.json_normalize()` to flatten it out.

```
data = [{'away_team': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
 'bookmakers': [{'key': 'fanduel',
                 'last_update': '2022-08-16T15:32:02Z',
                 'markets': [{'key': 'h2h',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
                                            'price': -530},
                                           {'name': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
                                            'price': 390}]},
                             {'key': 'spreads',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Nebraska Cornhuskers',
                                            'point': -12.5,
                                            'price': -110},
                                           {'name': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
                                            'point': 12.5,
                                            'price': -110}]},
                             {'key': 'totals',
                              'outcomes': [{'name': 'Over',
                                            'point': 50.5,
                                            'price': -110},
                                           {'name': 'Under',
                                            'point': 50.5,
                                            'price': -110}]}],
                 'title': 'FanDuel'}],
 'commence_time': '2022-08-27T16:30:00Z',
 'home_team': 'Northwestern Wildcats',
 'id': 'a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb',
 'sport_key': 'americanfootball_ncaaf',
 'sport_title': 'NCAAF'}
]
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 
                       record_path=['bookmakers', 'markets', 'outcomes'],
                       meta = [
                           'away_team', 'home_team','id', 'commence_time', 'sport_key', 'sport_title', 
                           ['markets', 'key'], 
                           ['markets','outcomes', 'key']
                           ],
                       errors='ignore',
                       record_prefix='outcomes.')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
           outcomes.name  outcomes.price  outcomes.point             away_team              home_team                                id         commence_time               sport_key sport_title markets.key markets.outcomes.key
0   Nebraska Cornhuskers            -530             NaN  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel                  h2h
1  Northwestern Wildcats             390             NaN  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel                  h2h
2   Nebraska Cornhuskers            -110           -12.5  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel              spreads
3  Northwestern Wildcats            -110            12.5  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel              spreads
4                   Over            -110            50.5  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel               totals
5                  Under            -110            50.5  Nebraska Cornhuskers  Northwestern Wildcats  a3fffa5803751d36f749c4b9388b9eeb  2022-08-27T16:30:00Z  americanfootball_ncaaf       NCAAF     fanduel               totals
```